# Why does a particular label tag does not vertically align?

Tags: html, css

In the below code,

```
<form class ="shoppingform" action="someaction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Step1: Your details<br>
            <div class="customername">
                <div class="center">
                    <label class="formlabel">Name:</label><input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="customeremail">
                <div class="center">
                    <label class="formlabel">Email:</label><input type="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="customerphone">
                <div class="center">
                    <label class="formlabel">Phone:</label><input type="tel">
                </div>
            </div><br>
            Step2: Delivery address
            <div class="customeraddress">
                <div class="center">
                    <label class="formlabel">Address:</label><textarea></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="customerpostcode">
                <div class="center">
                    <label class="formlabel">Post code:</label><input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="customercountry">
                <div class="center">
                    <label class="formlabel">Country:</label><input type="text">
                </div>
            </div><br>
            Step3: Card details
            <div class="customercardtype">
                <label class="formlabel">Cardtype:</label>
                <div class="cardtypecontainer">             
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="visa">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Visa.svg/175px-Visa.svg.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;VISA&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="amex">
                    <img src="http://www.hoax-slayer.com/images/american-express-security-update-scam-2.jpg">&nbsp;&nbsp;AMEX&nbsp;&nbsp;       
                    <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="mastercard">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/MasterCard_Logo.svg/2000px-MasterCard_Logo.svg.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Master card
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="customercardnumber">
                <div class="center">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="customersecuritycode">
                <div class="center">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="customercardname">
                <div class="center">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submitcontainer">
                    <input type="Submit" align="middle" value="BUY IT!">
            </div>
        </form>
```

---

```
.shoppingform{
                width:400px;
                height: 800px;
                background: #7CB9E8; /* url(some img)*/
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

.customername, .customeremail, .customerphone, .customeraddress, .customerpostcode, 
.customercountry, .customercardtype, .customercardnumber, .customersecuritycode, .customercardname{
                border: 1px solid white;
                color: black;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
                background: #B284BE;
                width:90%;
                border-radius: 5px;
                position: relative;
            }
.submitcontainer{
                padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
                width: 90%;
                position: relative;
                height: 5%;     
            }
.customername, .customeremail, .customerphone, .customerpostcode, .customercountry, 
.customercardnumber, .customersecuritycode, .customercardname{
                height:5%;
            }

.customeraddress{
                height:10%; 
            }
.customercardtype{
                height: 8%;
            }

.customername, .customeraddress, .customercardtype{
                margin-top:5px; 
            }

.customeremail, .customerphone, .customerpostcode, .customercountry, .customercardnumber, 
.customersecuritycode, .customercardname{
                margin-top: 2px;
            }

.formlabel{
        display:inline-block;
        width:30%;
        }

.customercardtype .formlabel{
                display:block;
                height: 20%
            }

.shoppingform   div > input{
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 60%;
            }

.shoppingform   div > textarea{
                border-radius: 5px;
                width:60%;
        }
.shoppingform .submitcontainer input{
                border-radius: 60px;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 30%;         
                position:absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%); /* works without position property*/
                transform: translateX(-50%);
            }
.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer{
                position: absolute;
                width: 95%;
                top: 40%;
                left: 2%;
                height: 50%;
}

.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer input{
    width: 5%;  
}

.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer img{
    width:5%;
}

.center{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 95%;
}
```

Why does particular `label` by name Address is not aligned vertically in the middle unlike other labels? as shown below.

[image]

Comment: To vertically align all the labels/textarea/input, I used `center`.

Comment: First let me know, what is the problem in this code? Wrt that particular label

Comment: @magreenberg some labels go inconsistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following CSS rule:

```
.customeraddress textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

All the other label/input fields are vertically aligned along the baseline.
For single lines, they appear vertically centered.

This works by vertically aligning the `textarea` to the `label` field next to it.  The vertical middle of the textarea field will be positioned an the level of the baseline of the label, which is basically what you need.

```css
.shoppingform{
                width:400px;
                height: 800px;
                background: #7CB9E8; /* url(some img)*/
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

.customername, .customeremail, .customerphone, .customeraddress, .customerpostcode, 
.customercountry, .customercardtype, .customercardnumber, .customersecuritycode, .customercardname{
                border: 1px solid white;
                color: black;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
                background: #B284BE;
                width:90%;
                border-radius: 5px;
                position: relative;
            }
.submitcontainer{
                padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
                width: 90%;
                position: relative;
                height: 5%;     
            }
.customername, .customeremail, .customerphone, .customerpostcode, .customercountry, 
.customercardnumber, .customersecuritycode, .customercardname{
                height:5%;
            }

.customeraddress{
                height:10%; 
            }
.customercardtype{
                height: 8%;
            }

.customername, .customeraddress, .customercardtype{
                margin-top:5px; 
            }

.customeraddress textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.customeremail, .customerphone, .customerpostcode, .customercountry, .customercardnumber, 
.customersecuritycode, .customercardname{
                margin-top: 2px;
            }

.formlabel{
        display:inline-block;
        width:30%;
        }

.customercardtype .formlabel{
                display:block;
                height: 20%
            }

.shoppingform   div > input{
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 60%;
            }

.shoppingform   div > textarea{
                border-radius: 5px;
                width:60%;
        }
.shoppingform .submitcontainer input{
                border-radius: 60px;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 30%;         
                position:absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%); /* works without position property*/
                transform: translateX(-50%);
            }
.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer{
                position: absolute;
                width: 95%;
                top: 40%;
                left: 2%;
                height: 50%;
}

.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer input{
    width: 5%;  
}

.customercardtype .cardtypecontainer img{
    width:5%;
}

.center{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<form class="shoppingform" action="someaction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Step1: Your details
  <br>
  <div class="customername">
    <div class="center">
      <label class="formlabel">Name:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customeremail">
    <div class="center">
      <label class="formlabel">Email:</label>
      <input type="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customerphone">
    <div class="center">
      <label class="formlabel">Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>Step2: Delivery address
  <div class="customeraddress">
    <div class="center">
      <label class="formlabel">Address:</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customerpostcode">
    <div class="center">
      <label class="formlabel">Post code:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customercountry">
    <div class="center">
      <label class="formlabel">Country:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>Step3: Card details
  <div class="customercardtype">
    <label class="formlabel">Cardtype:</label>
    <div class="cardtypecontainer">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="visa">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Visa.svg/175px-Visa.svg.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;VISA&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="amex">
      <img src="http://www.hoax-slayer.com/images/american-express-security-update-scam-2.jpg">&nbsp;&nbsp;AMEX&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="mastercard">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/MasterCard_Logo.svg/2000px-MasterCard_Logo.svg.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Master card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customercardnumber">
    <div class="center">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customersecuritycode">
    <div class="center">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customercardname">
    <div class="center">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="submitcontainer">
    <input type="Submit" align="middle" value="BUY IT!">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (add `vertical-align` to the `<textarea>`):

**CSS**

```
.shoppingform div > textarea {
    border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60%;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/KNG6n/80/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.shoppingform div > textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/5tm46thj/

Comment: textare is already vertically aligned. am asking about `label` tag adjacent to it

Comment: @overexchange also add some initial width to your textarea

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float:left;` instead of using `display:inline-block;` because display will align it from bottom and with float property you can perfectly align it according to you

```
.formlabel{
   float:left;
   width:30%;
}
```

Use above css for form label it will work perfectly and will align your label to exact top position.

Comment: Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjghtjfs/1/) link for the same. Its working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Just play with margin-top.

Try something like this:

```
.customeraddress label {
    margin-top:45%
}
```